# PHP7 non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php

I'm converting dates (Gregorian to Islamic Hijri). PHP 7 is displaying a "non-numeric" warning error. How can I amend the code?

This is for a Linux server running PHP 7.2 and Apache.  It worked as expected with PHP 5!  Have tried suggestions on stackoverflow, e.g. (intval) + (int),  to no avail!

```
1510    $date = "25/1/1999";
1511    $Gdate = explode ('/', $date) ; 
1512    $day = $Gdate[0];
1513    $month = $Gdate[1];
1514    $year = $Gdate[2];
1515
1516    $jgc=0;
1517    $m=$month;
1518    $y=$year;
1519    if($m<3) 
1520    {
1521        $m=$m+12;
1522        $y=$y-1;
1523    }
1524    $c=floor($y/100.);
1525
1526    if($y==1582 && $m>10) {$jgc=10;}
1527    if($y>1582) {$jgc=2-$c+floor($c/4.);}
1528
1529    $jd= floor(365.25*($y+4716))+floor(30.6001*($m+1))+$day+$jgc-1524;
```

I expect it to simply work and not produce the following error:
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in process.php on line **1529**

Comment: I can't replicate your problem: https://3v4l.org/vMqho works fine on *all* versions of PHP from 4.3 onward

Comment: Thank you, Nick.  Yes, it works.  I made a mistake in part of the script which meant emptied $date value, hence the error message,  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Trying this code on php 7.2.4 works without error so I think its something on your specific php.
Try to convert to integer your variables  before make calculatings

```
  $date = "25/1/1999";
    $Gdate = explode ('/', $date) ; 
    $day = (int)$Gdate[0];
    $month = (int)$Gdate[1];
    $year = (int)$Gdate[2];

    $jgc=0;
    $m=$month;
    $y=$year;
    if($m<3) 
    {
        $m=$m+12;
        $y=$y-1;
    }
    $c=floor($y/100.);

    if($y==1582 && $m>10) {$jgc=10;}
    if($y>1582) {$jgc=2-$c+floor($c/4.);}

    $jd= floor(365.25*($y+4716))+floor(30.6001*($m+1))+$day+$jgc-1524;
    echo $jd;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem says, you have a non numeric value.
Then, I think your date is malformed. 
 I suggest you use DateTime() library for correct parsing dates.